# How to merge data in SQL

Tags: sql, merge

I run a query every day to place in a file.  It is regarding effective date and term dates of coverage.  occasionally have a group that will actually term and become effective again the next day.  I need help with SQL code that will pick up the original effective date and the latest expiration date.  The example that I am giving is a very small part of the table.. due to hippa regulations. The SQL code that I currently am using is super easy query code and I have supplied just the  lines of data within the attachment.you will see where this member has 2 effect dates and 2 term dates  I need to display it as one..with 01/01/2018 as effect and 12/31/9999 as term.  cannot figure out how to add an attachment.. so I am just going to copy the two rows.

```
meme_altid  meme_eff    meme_trm
S409666X1E  2018-01-01  2018-12-31
S409666X1E  2019-01-01  9999-12-31
```

Comment: here is the code..SELECT [meme_altid]
      ,[meme_eff]
      ,[meme_trm]
  FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[effectdate]

Comment: I just copied a very small portion of the table into Northwind db

Answer (score 0):

Earliest eff and latest term?

```
Select meme_altid, Min(meme_eff) As eff, Max(meme_trm) As term From #tbl
Group By meme_altid
```